# ElasticSearch 2.2 - No search output

Tags: python, azure, elasticsearch

I am playing around with ES 2.2 trying to index some binary files (docx,pdf,xls ... ). I am running ES 2.2 with the attachment mapper plugin on a Azure VM.

What I did so far:

Created a text index:

```
curl -X PUT "${host}/test" -d '{
  "settings" : { "index" : { "number_of_shards" : 1, "number_of_replicas" : 0 }}
}
```

Created a mapping with type "attachment"

```
curl -X PUT "${host}/test/attachment/_mapping" -d '{
  "attachment" : {
    "properties" : {
      "file" : {
        "type" : "attachment",
        "fields" : {
          "title" : { "store" : "yes" },
         "content" : {"index" : "yes"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

Using a python script I took a simple .txt file an converted it to base64. I also tried docx files but for the sake of  clarity I thought .txt would be easier.

```
file64 = open(fname, "rb").read().encode("base64")
```

Running "`curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty'`" gives me output as expected

Output:

```
{
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "test",
      "_type" : "attachment",
      "_id" : "AVUz5IjHvyTlo4MUfxd0",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source" : {
        "file" : "aWNoIGJpbiBpbSBkb2t1bWVudA==\n",
        "title" : "datadump/test.txt.txt"
      }
    } ]
  }
}
```

But when I am running this query with the search term "im" (which is part of the encoded string in the output above) I get an empty output.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty' -d ' {
     "query" : { 
        "match" : { 
            "file" : "im" 
            }
        }
    }'
```

Output:

```
 {
  "took" : 1,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 0,
    "max_score" : null,
    "hits" : [ ]
  }
}
```

This is the code how I encode the documents:

```
def createEncodedTempFile(fname):
    import json

    file64 = open(fname, "rb").read().encode("base64")

    print 'writing JSON with base64 encoded file to temp file {}'.format(TMP_FILE_NAME)

    f = open(TMP_FILE_NAME, 'w')
    data = { 'file': file64, 'title': fname }
    json.dump(data, f) # dump json to tmp file
    f.close()
```

¨

Some more insights:
I am able to use the light weight search in order to search in title

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search?q=title:datadump//test'
```

This gives me this output

```
{"took":5,"timed_out":false,"_shards":"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.013555458,"hits":"_index":"test","_type":"attachment","_id":"AVU0bMivvyTlo4MUfxeY","_score":0.013555458,"_source":{"file":aWNoIGJpbiBpbSBkb2t1bWVudA==\n", "title": "datadump/test.txt.txt"}}]}}
```

But trying the same with searching in "file" gives me 0 hits:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search?q=file.content:Ich'
```

Do I miss something?

I am searching since yesterday with no luck. Any advice or help would be highly apreciated.

Cheers
Stefan

Comment: Have you tried to query `file.content` instead?

Comment: thanks for response, do you mean as follow?
    curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/test/_search?pretty' -d ' {
      "query" : { 
      "match" : { 
       "file.content" : "im" 
       }
      }
     }

Unfortunately the same output.

Comment: Can you try to search for `dokument` instead, `im` might be recognized as a stop word in German?

Comment: Thanks, but does not work as well (using file and file.content) :(

Comment: Can you remove the `\n` at the end of the base64 content, that might be one reason.

Comment: removed the "-d" in the search string. Output seems now fine. But received the following message "curl: (3) [globbing] nested brace in column 12
"

Comment: Well, removing -d ended in that the rest of the search string is being ignored. So not fixed :(. Regarding  `\n` intrestingly this is not in the .txt file.

Comment: No the newline must be added in your python code

Comment: I have added the code how I encode the documents in the main post. Do not see anything...

Comment: Can you run this and show the output you get? `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/plugins?v'`

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the standard [tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-tokenizers.html) in elasticsearch. The string  "aWNoIGJpbiBpbSBkb2t1bWVudA==\n" in "file" breaks down into separate strings. So when you search for it won't have the exact string.

Using [Keyword tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-keyword-tokenizer.html) could solve this

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed and compared the documents for ES [2.2](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/binary.html) & [1.3](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/mapping-attachment-type.html). It seems that the `Binary datatype` instead of the `Attachment Type` in the version 2.x.

Please try to refer to the document https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/binary.html to recreate the mapping.

Hope it helps.